# Load JS & CSS based on controls loaded in HTML page

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui, wijmo

I am using Kendo UI controls and Wijmo control. The page mostly consists of HTML5 and Kendo Grid. Also, If I would like ot add any Wijmo control to the page; then how to load the appropriate JS & CSS files related to the controls without one overriding the other controls script files.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For Wijmo controls on any page, you just need to refer the Wijmo Open and Wijmo Pro js after adding jQuery references. You can check this link for the js/css files required by Wijmo widgets:
http://wijmo.com/downloads/